# queue management system

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++, messaging

I want create simple Queue Management system for my project. System will work like this example. Lets say there are 3 offices

1. Person pushes to button "Office 1"
2. Software generates auto-incremented number, adds him to queue (db) and prints check with generated number.
3. And shows last 3 values of queue on big screen.
4. When client side (workers of office 1) pushes the "next" button. It removes current active number and changes state of last number in queue to active.

Are there any Open Source Queue Management Software applications that I can use in my project or i need to write it?

Comment: Doing the queuing itself the way you describe it is trivial. The rest vastly depends on your hardware: when you say “person pushes a button”, do you mean on a normal computer? Or do you have some special HW for that?

Comment: no it's normal pc (server side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I have understood your requirement, but I will assume the question comes down to the fact that you need some kind of message queue solution.

Windows comes with a standard message queue solution which you can install from the windows installation disks and use from .NET using the [System.Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.aspx) namespace.

Alternatively, if you are looking for an open source solution, you can take a look at [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/). It is written in Java, but you can also interact with it from .NET and many other languages and platforms.

Comment: @Tural, what type of queue is it then? Do you just want an in memory queue? Will `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

recently, i have done a QMS which is using Bluetooth Technology.
Just using a mobile phone to connect to the queue server. For more information, please visit: www.luvotech.com/web4

Note: the web site is not fully construct, may have some error/mistake.